# Graphics error: Plot rendering error in Rstudio server 0.99

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm having an issue with the Rstudio server installed in the cluster where I work. The server stopped working last month and I had to restart it, but now, we are unable to create plots with this software.

When we try to create a plot like:

```
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)

y <- x

plot(x,y) #This is just an example
```

It returns:

`Error in .Call(.rs.routines$rs_createGD) : first argument must be a string (of length 1) or native symbol reference`

And its not a problem with R itself, since I can create plots using the command line version.
I tried to find an answer to this problem everywhere...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `<-` in stead of `->`?

Comment: It was a typing error, sorry.

Comment: We're experiencing the same issues on 0.99.491

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you at all. We just upgraded to R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness" w/ RStudio Version 0.99.491. After doing a bunch of testing due to getting the same exact error you mentioned above I finally was able to kick the warning after creating a new project within the RStudio interface --

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0   
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 12 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

After upgrading to RStudio version 1.0.143 we've been able to use RStudio without issue.